# Finding Cartesian Equation giving Parametric Equations

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, parametric

The equations are:
$$ x = cos(\pi - t), y = sin(\pi - t), 0 \le t \le \pi$$

I don't really understand what to do. On the last problem I had:

$$ x = cos2t, y = sin2t, 0 \le t \le \pi  $$

and I just used the basic unit circle of $ x^2 + y^2 = 1 $ but I'm not sure how it was really implemented.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $x^2+y^2=1$ for all $t$

Comment: @Ataulfo so no matter what is with the $t$, such as a 2 or a "$\pi - $" it will always be $x^2 + y^2 = 1$? aka a unit circle with radius 1?

Comment: The range of $t$ will tell you which part of the circle the equation represents.  So you need to figure out which part of the circle is included.  The parametric equations also give you a "direction" along the circle, whereas the Cartesian equation doesn't have that directional info.

Comment: @Bye_World but it will still be a unit circle of radius one correct?

Comment: *Part* of the unit circle, yes.

Comment: @Bye_World Yes sorry I should have rephrased that. It is initially the unit circle, but the $t$ tells us direction and the correct part of the unit circle. Thank you much :). I didn't know if the radius would still be 1 or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is to consider $\pi-t=u$.  (This will make it easier to solve.)  Now we have:$$x=\cos(u),y=\sin(u)$$Then, we could square both sides to get:$$x^2=\cos^2(u),y^2=\sin^2(u)$$Add the two equations to get:$$x^2+y^2=\cos^2(u)+\sin^2(u)=1$$The last part was the commonly known trigonometric identity derived from the Pythagorean theorem.  So the solution is $$x^2+y^2=1$$